# How to block content on mainpage on youtube using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have chrome and I was wondering if there was some kind of a addon where I could block all the videos on the main page of Youtube's website.

I have children and I don't like the videos they show on the main page.

Comment: The videos that are displayed on the front page are based on your viewing history.  You are aware of that right?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I'm referring to the videos even when your browser cache is deleted, any computer I just want to block it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after [Parental Controls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u00yKwGFpS0). Here's how to do it:

1. Visit YouTube and log in to your account. If you don't have an
   existing account, you can click the "Create Account" link to
   register.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page and locate the "Safety mode"
   option. The "Safety mode" option will be listed as "Off."
3. Click the "Off" link. You will be asked to select a safety mode.
4. Check the box next to "On," and then click the "Save" button. After
   you click the "Save" button, you will have the option to lock the
   safety mode on the web browser you are using.
5. Click the "Save and lock Safety Mode on this browser" button to save
   your new settings. This option allows you to keep your YouTube
   settings in safety mode after you log out. If you want to set the
   safety mode for an additional web browser, open your new browser and
   repeat Step one through Step five.